# Ansible Playbook => With_items . Multiple vars

Tags: ansible

```
ansible-playbook Try.yml -e "a='01','60'"
```

Step1.

```
vars:
     aa: [ '{{ a }}' ]

  tasks:
  - name: TEST
    debug: msg="{{ item }}"
    with_items: '{{aa}}'
```

result

```
ok: [----------] => (item=01','60) => {
    "item": "01','60",
    "msg": "01','60"
}
```

Step 2.

```
vars:
     aa: [ "01","60" ]

  tasks:
  - name: TEST
    debug: msg="{{ item }}"
    with_items: '{{aa}}'
```

result

```
ok: [----------] => (item=01) => {
    "item": "01",
    "msg": "01"
}

ok: [----------] => (item=60) => {
    "item": "60",
    "msg": "60"
}
```

How can i do like Step2.

```
a='01','60'"
```

the values of a is not regular , The quantity is not regular too

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I had understood correctly your problem but:

the content of the extra vars command line params can be a JSON formatted string. So you can avoid the `vars: aa` in playbook and pass the command in this way:

`ansible-playbook Try.yml -e '{"aa": ["01","60"]}'`